# bulk remove the required paramater fron custom option magento

Tags: database, magento, field, product, unset

i have around 10000 products in my database which all have custom options and they all are set to required.

I need to unset required.
Please suggest me how can i do this dynamically.
I don't want to do it one by one from magento admin because that will take forever

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reset the `required` field for all custom options of all products here is a quick & dirty way of doing it.

All the custom options are stored in the table `catalog_product_option`.
The column name that decides if the option is required or not is `is_require`.

So running this query should do the trick.

```
UPDATE `catalog_product_option` SET `is_require` = 0 WHERE 1
```

Add the table prefix if you have one.

Answer (score 0):

you can update those product's required parameter by using **import product by csv**. I think, you have imported products by csv. simply copy that SKU and custom field option into new csv file.

And import Again those products. It will update custom option required field as you want

Answer (score 0):

I'm just expanding on Marius' answer. I needed to do this but only for a bunch of custom options I'd made required by accident. I figure it might help someone else who made a similar miscalculation! :-D

```
UPDATE catalog_product_option o
JOIN catalog_product_option_title t ON t.option_id=o.option_id 
SET o.is_require = 0
WHERE t.title = 'Additional Comments'
AND o.is_require = 1
```

Luckily the options I imported all had the same title so I was able to filter it that way.

If you're using SKU's for your custom options, you could probably further simplify the query as it requires no joins.

```
UPDATE catalog_product_option o
SET o.is_require = 0
WHERE o.sku = 'SKU1234'
AND o.is_require = 1
```

^ not tested that but looking at the structure of the table that should work.